# Is there something like "target = parent" in XForms?

Tags: html, xforms

Like in the title, I'm looking for solution for replacing HTML's "target = parent" with XForms. I've got iframe with XForms and I need to communicate with parent page. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

XForms specifications do not yet include this. But, similarly, in XSLTForms, it is possible, as an extension, to access instances in the "opener" form.

Do you need to communicate or do you want to replace all the parent?

-Alain

Comment: Because of wide use of XForms both ways will be considered. So, how to do that with xsltforms?